# expected primary-expression before '[' token for templates

Tags: templates, dictionary, foreach

I am trying to create a template for any container so 
I can print out its content. I am specifically trying 
with a map, I have tried all the syntaxes, but always get
some error. I'd appreciate you could help me to find out what 
is wrong.

```
template <typename A, typename B>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<A, B>& p)
{
  return os << '(' << p.first << ", " << p.second << ')';
}


template <typename Container>
void print_container(std::ostream& os, const Container& cont)
{
  typename Container::value_type value_type;
  os << "[\n";
  std::for_each(cont.begin(), cont.end(),
                            [&] (const type& v) { os << v; });
  os << "\n]\n";
}
```

I get the following error when I try to call print_container
with a map.

```
print_container(cout,mymap);
```

Error:

```
In file included from ../src/STL_Library.cpp:10:
../src/STL_Library.h: In function 'void print_container(std::ostream&, const Container&)':
../src/STL_Library.h:31: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
../src/STL_Library.h:31: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
../src/STL_Library.h:31: error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
make: *** [src/STL_Library.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling with C++11 support?

Comment: I don't know what do you make you think that is not supported?Is there any warning that indicates you that?Otherwise do you know if there is another way to write this piece of code so it is compatible?Thank you

Comment: No, I'm just asking you to check that you are actually compiling with the proper version of C++.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to alias `value_type` so, use `typedef`

```
template <typename Container>
void print_container(std::ostream& os, const Container& cont)
{
  typedef typename Container::value_type value_type;
/*~~~~~~~*/

  std::for_each(cont.begin(), cont.end(),
                            [&] (const value_type& v) { os << v; });
                                      /~~~~~~~~~~*/

}
```

Comment: @r2d2 Please don't edit answers to ask questions, see [here](http://rextester.com/HSIBX9947)